# OpenGL Order of VBO binding

Tags: c++, qt, opengl, vbo

If I'm trying to do some OpenGL 3.3+ style VBO graphics, is it alright for me to first, enable attribute arrays and set vertex attribute pointers, then in an often refreshing VBO, load fresh data and bind a GL_ARRAY_BUFFER and GL_ELEMENT_ARRAY_BUFFER then call drawELements? I have code that is crashing on drawElements, and I'm wondering if its because the order of my calls is messed up. I'll also mention that this is under the guise of Qt 5.

Comment: can you show the code in drawElements that is causing the problem? Also what the error is.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Whn you set your attribute pointers, it is crucial to have the correct `GL_ARRAY_BUFFER` bound. The current `GL_ARRAY_BUFFER_BINDING` *at the time of the `glVertexAttribPointer()` call* will become part of that attribute pointer state. It does not matter which `GL_ARRAY_BUFFER` is bound at draw time (in contrast to the `GL_ELEMENT_ARRAY_BUFFER` which is relevant for the `glDrawElements()` family of GL functions.

Comment: I thought they were seperate, where you could just determine the VertexAttributePointers and they would somehow stay that way. Thanks!